# How to change the system shortdatetime format using delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, date

I am going to try and make the question as simple as possible.

How do i either convert the system date to a format i would like, and still keep it a date and not a string.
Or how do i get the system's date format, to adjust my dates accordingly.

When i call

```
FormatShortdateTime('d/M/yyyy',Date);
```

I get the correct date as string, but cannot convert it back to a Tdate and use it, then it clashes with the system date settings.

If i can get the system shortdate format the problem would be solved.

Comment: It's accessible through the [`FormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.FormatSettings) variable, so write it as `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := ...`. Besides, which problem did changing global configuration based on local settings resolved ? I guess there could be a solution rather than workaround.

Comment: That doesn't really sound like the solution to any problem

Comment: @TLama i tried FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='d/M/yyyy'; and still got an error when comparing the dates: "18/2/2014" is not a valid date.

i compare alot of different date formats, can basically be any format want my software to basically convert all dates to 1 constant format. preferably without changing the system date, but if necessary i will change the system date format

Comment: Still better will be declare a variable holding your global format settings and pass this format to all your formatting functions. However, I can't explain why you *"got an error"* at least because I don't know the context nor the error you got.

Comment: The problem is my system date, it is d-M-yyyy. so datetostr and strtodate keeps giving errors

Comment: No, your problem is that you won't use the conversion functions that accept a format settings parameter. Next step for you is to learn about those and stop frabbing the global settings.

Comment: @Tlama i do define const DefFormat:String = 'd/M/yyyy'; and call that.

The date in my table is format 'd/M/yyyy' and my system is 'd-M-yyyy' whenever i use datetostr or strtodate i get this error "project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message'"18/2/2014' is not a valid date'."

Comment: @user3271392 Please stop using comments to ask your question. Edit the question to provide an SSCCE, and let us give you a good answer.

Comment: @Davidheffernan do you have a solution for me please?

Comment: @user3271392 I absolutely have a solution to your question. You just need to ask the question.

Comment: @davidheffernan The question asked properly now?

Comment: No, I still cannot understand it. Sorry. I don't understand why you define `DefFormat` and never use it. I don't know what `GetFormat` is. I don't see why you have both 'DD/MM/YYYY' and 'd/M/yyyy'. I don't know why you want to use the global format settings at all. Do you know about passing format settings as parameters?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have eddited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Your latest edit to the question makes no sense. You have added a function that does not compile. Honestly, you need to slow down and try to do some debugging at your end. Try to come up with a coherent and repeatable set of facts.

Comment: Whenever you talk about the "format" of a date, you're talking about strings. Strings are not dates. To discuss converting a date to a particular format means making a string, which is not a date, so it's nonsense to suggest keeping it as a date. If you want a date, then use `TDate` and forget about formats at all. Store *dates* in your database, and read them as dates. Life's much easier with situation-appropriate data types. String is rarely that.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

The answer below refers to the original question that you asked. You've edited the question multiple times now to ask different questions. You really should not do that and it is a sign that you should spend more time understanding the problem before asking questions.

Even so, the final part of the answer, probably still contains the advice that you need. Namely to stop using conversion functions that rely on the global `FormatSettings` variable, and always use conversion functions that are passed format settings as a parameter.

---

The date values in your database are not stored in the format that you expect. This program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  fs: TFormatSettings;
begin
  fs := TFormatSettings.Create;
  fs.ShortDateFormat := 'd/M/yyyy';
  Writeln(DateToStr(StrToDate('18/2/2014', fs)));
end.
```

produces the following output on my machine:

```
18/02/2014
```

I guess on your machine it would produce a different output because your short date format is different from mine. But the point is that the call to `StrToDate` succeeds.

Clearly the values stored in your database are not in the form you claim. Because you claim that the above code would lead to a date conversion error in the call to `StrToDate`.

---

Let's step back and look at the initial part of your question:

> I would like to know how to convert dates without having the system date influence the software.

The code in the answer above gives you an example of how to do that. Modern versions of Delphi overload the date and time conversion functions. There are overloads that accept `TFormatSettings` parameters, and overloads without such a parameter. The `TFormatSettings` parameter is used to control the format used for the conversion. The overloads that do not receive such a parameter use the global `FormatSettings` instance declared in the `SysUtils` unit.

What you should do to avoid having the system settings influence your conversions is to only use conversion functions that accept a format settings parameter.

On the other hand, if you want the system settings to influence your conversions, then feel free to call the overloads that use the global format settings variable.

My code above illustrates both. The conversion from string to date requires a fixed format, not varying with local system settings. The conversion from date to string is designed to show a date using the prevailing local system settings.

Comment: if (StrToDate(Datalive.users.Fieldbyname('last_backup').AsString))<ConvertDate(Date) then

I need to convert the date of the system and then convert them. I do not know the system date, so i cannot change my dateformat to that format. But when i try i get the date error if named before.

Comment: That comment is completely opaque to me. You claimed that your dates are stored in the database in the format `'18/2/2014'`. And that when you used `StrToDate` with a short date format of `'d/M/yyyy'` then the call to `StrToDate` fails. Given that information my conclusion is that the strings in your database are not in the format that you believe them to be. Or perhaps you are reading them out incorrectly. Or perhaps the information that you told us is plain wrong.

Comment: ok, let me try and make it clear. I need to convert the date i get from the system to the date format i use. and keep it as a date not string.

if i call formatdatetime('d/M/yyyy',Date), i get the right format as string, But if i say Strtodate(formatdatetime('d/M/yyyy',Date)), that is when i get the error. understand? i can convert it to string in the right format, trying to use it as a date, gives me the error

Comment: Not in comments. What you need to do is give us an SSCCE in the question. Going back to my previous comment, please can you address the points I raised. *You claimed that your dates are stored in the database in the format `'18/2/2014'`. And that when you used `StrToDate` with a short date format of `'d/M/yyyy'` then the call to `StrToDate` fails.* My answer shows that your claims are incorrect and that you don't understand the problem and don't know what values you are dealing with. Your next step is to do some debugging. Then provide a clear SSCCE.

Comment: I know the original question, but my efforts to addapt your methods fails.
My system format is d-M-yyyy, when i try StrToDate(FormatShortdate('d/M/yyyy',Date)). The system's settings clash with mine. So do you know how to get the system date settings? i can swing it arround, and addapt to the system.

Comment: @user3271392 I stand by my advice. Passing format settings is the correct way to control the conversion and avoid relying on the system settings. If you want to do it a different way, expect no help from me. I don't have any enthusiasm to teach you the wrong solution to your problem. In any case, `@TLama` already told your that in the first comment to your question. I do have some advice for you. Slow down and understand what you are doing. You would have solved the problem by now if you had thought about it more carefully rather than your current scattergun approach.

Comment: FYI, starting with XE5, the global formatting variable(s) no longer exist. They have finally been removed. Every formatting function that previously used the global variable(s) now creates a local `TFormatSettings` internally. So if you want to customize the formattings, you MUST use `TFormatSettings` yourself on a per-call basis, there is no longer any option to customize the formattings globally for the entire process.

Answer (score -1):

I would advice creating own TFormatSettings variable

older delphi versions

```
var
  fs: TFormatSettings;
begin
  fs := TFormatSettings.Create;
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, fs);
end.
```

This will create your own formatSettings (filled with system format) so you won't alter the default one.

Now what's important is that '/' in shortDateFormat will be replaced by dateSeparator so if you do this

```
fs.ShortDateFormat:='M/d/yyyy';
fs.dateSeparator:='?';
```

your input should be like this

```
strtodate('12?30?1899', fs);
```

or if other way around you will end up with string: '12?30?1899';

I think that your problems originate from that you don't ask what dateSeparator is used. That would lead to problems if what program expects is '30-12-1899' but he gets '30/12/1899' from you.

Comment: I would like to see reason why did I get vote down... I would be more than happy to learn where I am wrong.